# How to create attribute only for objects that satisfy a condition in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I would like to know how to define attributes only for objects that satisfy a condition raising an error if an object without the condition is asked for that attribute.

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, number_of_variables:int):
        self.number_of_variables = number_of_variables
        if self.is_univariate():
            self.nroots = compute_number_of_roots(self) # This function returns the number of roots

    def is_univariate(self):
        return True if self.number_of_variables==1 else False

    def number_of_roots(self):
        if self.is_univariate():
            return compute_number_of_roots(self) # This function returns the number of roots
        else:
            raise Exception("Number of roots is not defined for multivariate polynomials.")
```

Here, defining `p = Polynomial(3)` calling `p.number_of_roots()` raise the desired error, but when trying to get the attribute `p.nroots` an error that doesn't return a lot of information is given.

**Taking into account the answers** I think this is how it should be done:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, number_of_variables:int):
        self.number_of_variables = number_of_variables

    def is_univariate(self):
        return True if self.number_of_variables==1 else False

    @property
    def nroots(self):
        if self.is_univariate():
            return compute_number_of_roots(self) # This function returns the number of roots
        else:
            raise Exception("Number of roots is not defined for multivariate polynomials.")
```

Comment: Just define it as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and protect access in the same way you do `p.number_of_roots()`.

Comment: Set `nroots` to `None`, or create a `property` to access it.

Comment: I modified the question by adding a solution I believe to be good using your answers. However, in the link of @Axe319 properties are defined in the `__init__` functions preceded by an underscore. Is this good practice?

Comment: @TeresodelRíoAlmajano it looks good to me. The underscore just indicates that the variable is private and keeps it from conflicting with the `nroots` property. If `compute_number_of_roots` isn't expensive to compute and/or you want generate it each time on demand this seems like a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @TeresodelRíoAlmajano To me even the first code that you wrote is doing what the title of your question is asking. I think what you want is in fact to be able to set a different error message than the automatic default attribute error message for a specific attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how do you want to access the number of roots from outside the class. Wheter from the method `number_of_roots` or from the attribute `nroots` It should be only one, if not is confusing.

Also note that you compute the number of roots each time the method `number_of_roots` is called. You should return the `nroots` attribute instead.

So, if you have a method `number_of_roots` then the attribute `nroots` should be considered private and only be accessed from the class.

(Although python does not have private attributes, you should better rename nroots to _nroots to show that it is private. But that is only a hint for the programmer)

So as `nroots` is only accesed from the class, it is sufficient that the class does not read `nroots` when it is not defined.

Now if you want to get the number of roots from outside the class directly as an attribute, then you should define a property `nroot` which returns the `_nroot` attribute if it is appropiate and elsecase raise the error.

```
@property
def nroots(self):

    if self.is_univariate():
        return self._nroots:

    else:
      raise Exception('...')
```

The `_nroot` attribute should be initialized in `__init__`

So summing up:

1. Initialize `_nroot` in `__init__` if the polynomial is univariate. If not, `_nroot` is left undefined.
2. return `_nroot` from a function of from a property.